# Why detailViewController is not in UISplitViewController.viewControllers anymore?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I use UISplitViewController to build my app. Both the master view controller and detail view controller are UINavigationControllers, as illustrated in the Figure.
[image: Storyboard]

In the viewDidLoad() functions of both master vc and detail vc, the following code is inserted:

```
    println(self.splitViewController!.viewControllers.count)
    for vc in self.splitViewController!.viewControllers {
        println(vc.hashValue)
    }
```

The result is:

master vc.viewDidLoad()

```
2
140692681984032
140692680836304
```

detaiVC.viewDidLoad()

```
1
140692681984032
```

It turns out that in detaiVC.viewDidLoad(), detailVC is not in splitViewController.viewControllers any more. Why?

Answer (score 2):

When running your app in a compact width, the splitviewcontroller will be compacted. ie the `var viewControllers` property only contains 1 view controller.

From the documentation:

> When the split view interface is expanded, this property contains two
>   view controllers; when it is collapsed, this property contains only
>   one view controller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISplitViewController/viewControllers

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since there is only 1 view controller, how can I make both masterVC and detailVC visible?

Comment: You will need a device with a regular width. Ie iPad or iPhone 6 plus in landscape.